# Why won't this regex work?

Tags: python, regex

Im try to match ip addresses and have come up with the following regular expression for python. I just cannot understand why this wont work. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
r"[0-255]\.[0-255]\.[0-255]\.[0-255]"
```

Comment: `[0-255]` will match only one of the single digits `0,1,2,5`

Comment: And the `r""` will make the backslashes literal. You aren't escaping the dots

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/ip.html

Comment: This task is a rather poor fit for regular expressions. Try something like. `octets = address.split("."); valid = len(octets) == 4 and all(segment.isdigit() and int(segment) < 256 for segment in octets)`: ...

Answer (score 2):

Because `[0-255]` means any char between `0 to 2 or 5`. switch to something like

```
r"^(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?).(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?).(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?).(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)$"
```

Comment: Should leading zeros be allowed?

Comment: @cricket_007 I'm not sure that leading 0's are forbidden with the norm. I'm gonna take a look